# JSF Intercept and Log All ActionEvents

Tags: java, jsf

I'm working on a rather large (and buggy) JSF application, and the users often complain of issues that we have trouble reproducing.

Is it possible to intercept the creation of all ActionEvents so that I can log their creation?

If not, is there an automatic way (JSF or other) that I can improve the logging so that it spits out all user actions?

Comment: Do your actions pass through any form of filter for any security reasons?

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.util.Logging and have loggers log when the method is being called, the input parameters with which it is being called, what it is returning and when it is ending and any exceptions if occurred. This will give you information about what actual data are users entering and if there is anything wrong with this.
You can do something in PhaseListener as well for Invoke Application phase but this may impact some performance on all the requests. I think better to do it in action event handler method.

Comment: No, it will be better doing it in `PhaseListener` for inoke application phase as explained.